# タグを作成中にキーボードで漢字の変換を行えば、投稿してしまう

Tags: 機能の要求, タグ

新しい質問を投稿している際に「タグ」を書かないといけません。

新しいタグを登録すると、キーボードで漢字の変換を行ったら、変換する為に<kbd>Enter</kbd>を押せば、途中で（変換を完成する前に）投稿してしまいます。

改善方法：

「タグ」欄に<kbd>Enter</kbd>を投稿しないように設定する。

Comment: 日本語変換ソフトを使っている場合にはEnterを多用するので、これは是非直して欲しいです。