# 投稿の編集が無効な場合に、「編集」リンクのフォントサイズが周囲より大きい

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

例えば今一般ユーザーで [タグを作成中にキーボードで漢字の変換を行えば、投稿してしまう](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A7%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0-%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86) を見ると、質問に対するアクションメニュー部分がこうなっています:

[image: 編集に注目]

ロードされているCSS:

http://cdn.sstatic.net/jameta/all.css?v=3c6f96d51af1

メニュー部分のHTML:

```html
<div class="post-menu">
  <a href="/q/156/30" title="この質問への短い固定リンク" class="short-link" id="link-post-156">共有</a>
  <span class="lsep">|</span>
  <span class="disabled-link" title="メタ サイトでは、タグ wiki でない投稿の編集を推奨することはできません。">編集</span>
  <span class="lsep">|</span>
  <a href="#" class="close-question-link" title="この質問のクローズに投票する (クローズされると新しい回答は追加できません)" data-questionid="156" data-isclosed="false">閉じる</a>
  <span class="lsep">|</span>
  <a href="#" class="flag-post-link" title="重大な問題がある、またはモデレーターの注意を喚起するためにこの投稿を通報する" data-postid="156">通報</a>
</div>
```

有効なリンクに適用されているフォントサイズのルール:

```css
.post-menu>a {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

無効なリンクに適用されているフォントサイズのルール:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: これは再現できていないらしいです。まだ問題として残っていますか？

Comment: @jmac まだ再現します。質問本文に、こちらのブラウザで確認したスタイル設定を追記しました。

Comment: デザイナーにHTMLとCSSを提供しました。協力ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

この問題は解決しているようで、他と同じ大きさで表示されています。色も他と同じになっており、無効であることが見た目で解りませんが、これは英語版とも同じであるため、意図的なデザインと思われます。

現在の様子（赤背景のエラーメッセージは「編集」をクリックすると出ます）:

> [image: スクリーンショット]